# Update below table values by clicking submit button PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, wamp

I am novice to php and need to figure out how to add new row with data which was given by in another table and finally calculate the total.

[image]

First table connects to two tables named as Product which contains the data of the product and Batch which contains the data about `price`, `exp_dt`, `batchno` etc.

Please help me to do this

Comment: Jesus said you put some code here or what you have tried.

Comment: are you using any javascript library or do you want to use pure js?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ is what you need to read

Answer (score 0):

Read about forms, ajax.I not much aware of mentioned technology but I am giving you initial hint to start,

- create form with first image
- add input like name, quantity, discount etc.
- add submit button like ADD
- post this form as ajax
- after getting okay response modify below table and append same record row.

This answer will be more understandable after reading about FORMS AND AJAX,

Better you search out script for that over internet

Comment: thnx sir, but is there any way to create it using javascript ?

Comment: yes, believe me it would be little hard as of now , try learn jquery or ajax.you can easily find over internet about that

Comment: i don't know why you need ajax for a simple javascript dom manipulation

Comment: @DevZero its DB insertion